# Is there away to start/stop a mock service via groovy script as one of the groovy test steps?

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

I'd like to be able to start mock service in SOAPUI on test case setup script and close it through tear down script.
I figured out how to start the service in setup script:

```
def project = null
def projectName = "myproject"
def workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getWorkspace();

//if running Soapui
if(workspace != null){
    project = workspace.getProjectByName(projectName)
}
else {
    log.error("Can't find workspace")
}
if (project != null) {
    log.info("Project " + projectName + " located!")    
    project.getMockServiceByName("myMockService").start(); 
     log.info("Project myMockService started!")
} else {
    log.error("Can't find " + projectName + " project, please start mock service manually") 
}
```

But having difficulties obtaining a reference to already running mock service in order to stop it.
Any suggestion what should I script in tear down script to stop the service?
[image]

Comment: I believe that is not the right way to do. The way it should be done to use SOAPUI_HOME/bin/mocktestrunner to start the mock service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
def project = null
def projectName = "myproject"
def workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getWorkspace();

//if running Soapui
if(workspace != null){
    project = workspace.getProjectByName(projectName)
}
else {
    log.error("Can't find workspace")
}
if (project != null) {
    log.info("Project " + projectName + " located!")    
    project.getMockServiceByName("mymockservice")getMockRunner().stop(); 
     log.info("Project mymockservice stopped!")
} else {
    log.error("Can't find " + projectName + " project, please stop mock service manually")  
}
```